# Why is my main menu image wrong sized on launch but not after a game?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have an image that loads on a MainMenu scene and appears as wrong sized when the game launches but then after finishing a level returns you to the MainMenu again the image appears right sized.

The first time the image appears to be three quarters or 4/5 of the size of the screen from left to right.  The image has a white background around it so I can see a black tall rectangle in the right side of the screen on the main menu's first launch.  But after a game it is sized properly and the white background image is sized properly.

Anybody ever have this happen?

Here is the init code for the MainMenuLayer:

```
-(id)init {
    if( (self=[super initWithColor:ccc4(255,255,255,255)]) ) {
        [[GameManager sharedGameManager] playBackgroundTrack:BACKGROUND_TRACK_MAIN_MENU];
        CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"MainMenu-iPad.png"];
            [background setPosition:ccp(screenSize.width/2,screenSize.height/2)];
            [self addChild:background];
            [self displayMainMenu];
        } else {
            CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"MainMenu.png"];
            [background setPosition:ccp(screenSize.width/2,screenSize.height/2)];
            [self addChild:background];
            [self displayMainMenu];
        }
-
```

It works fine on the simulator though...

Comment: code? Code? Show us how you set it up.

Comment: Here is the git link: https://gist.github.com/quique123/5050916

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image was apparently being cached even after clean and build!  I ended up replacing the image by removing the original and adding the same one but with some markers just to make sure it got replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Print screen position, if position is wrong then put you code in onEnter instead of init.

[See this thread in Stack overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488515/ccdirector-shareddirectorwinsize-is-wrong/12488926#12488926)

```
-(id)init {
    if( (self=[super initWithColor:ccc4(255,255,255,255)]) ) {
       }
     return self;
}



-(void)onEnter {
        [super onEnter];
        [[GameManager sharedGameManager] playBackgroundTrack:BACKGROUND_TRACK_MAIN_MENU];
        CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

         CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"MainMenu.png"];
         [background setPosition:ccp(screenSize.width/2,screenSize.height/2)];
         [self addChild:background];
         [self displayMainMenu]; 
}
```

Comment: Well I did this but I still get the image wrong-sized.  :(. Why would it only happen on launch and not after its loaded a second time?

Comment: print image size. For hd, placed hd image?

Comment: i have all 4 sized images: 480x320, 960x640, 1024x768, 2048x1536 for png, -hd.png, -iPad.png and -iPad-hd.png respectively.  It works for other devices and like i said, it works fine after a second run.  Its just the first run thats messing things up.

Comment: im printing image size, by doing background.contentSize.height and width, and i get 1024 x 768 for all idiomiPads and 480x320 for all iPhones.

Comment: instead of -iPad.png put -ipad.png and -iPad-hd.png to -ipadhd.png, in code as well as in image in disk. That must work...and no need to specify hd image in code....it takes...

Comment: ok but all my other images are -iPad & -iPad-hd.  And they work fine.  Furthermore, this very image works fine after ive gone through the main menu once and played a game level and then return to the main menu.  Its just the first time the mm runs that it has that problem.