# CCDirector wrong window size on iPhone5

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

This is the first time i have this problem .

```
    -(void)onEnter
{

    [super onEnter];

    winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    NSLog(@"wins:%f",winSize.height);
```

is returning `480` on iPhone5 simulator .
Whats wrong here ?? its in onEnter ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Default-568h@2x.png (640x1136)  to your Xcode target.

Already added then checkout my answer here:
 [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]winSize] is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488515/ccdirector-shareddirectorwinsize-is-wrong/12488926#12488926)